# I can't access "mypage.com/user1" through browser (404 not found) but I can through my page when (deployed on netlify)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, svelte, netlify

Hi I have a svelte application in netlify deployed (manual drag and drop of 'public' folder) and first everything worked without a problem.
Now I can access the main page (mypage.com) without problems, und when I navigate internally on the main page it refers me to "mypage.com/user1".

But when I'm directly entering "mypage.com/help" in my browser I get an '404 not found'.
Only thing I remember I did was changing the favicon.png at the title in the header but this shouldn't be related to that.

When I'm running the app on local, everything works without any problems.

Comment: This sound like a single-page application that doesn't correctly handle routes. What web server do you use? Do you have to redirect all requests to the index page?

Comment: @jabaa So it's just the compiled svelte app drag&dropped to netlify so I guess node? Yes, it's single page. I don't know that much about routing, the only "routing" I implemented was `<Route path="/:id" component="{Board}" />` and a `navigate('/user1')` in the script after clicking a button. So I assume, when I entered a link with 'mypage.com/blabla' the router on the main page redirected it to the Board component. As I said on local it works without any problems.

Comment: You have to configure the web server to redirect all requests. It's impossible to help without more details about the web server. When you navigate in a SPA, the URL is modified by the frontend JavaScript. The server isn't involved. When you try to directly access a specific route, the web server has to know how to handle the route. Are you running a Node.js dev server on localhost and Apache httpd on Netlify?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to redirect all requests to the index file.
In netlify, you create a new file called `_redirects` inside the root folder and enter one line there: `/* /index.html 200`.